# What is the idiomatic way to install a Debian package using Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

Below my code for installing vcider.  I am learning chef but have not seen anything for installing a dpkg.  I would like to use version in the script.    The code below works.

```
script "install_vcider" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
  wget https://my.vcider.com/m/downloads/vcider_2.0.1b_amd64.deb
  dpkg -i vcider__amd64.deb
  EOH
end
```

Even with the code above can I replace 2.0.1b with #{version}?
    attribute file -> default[:vcider][:version] 2.0.1b

```
recipe file - > version = node[:vcider][:version]
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Right Thing is to use the built-in resource types. Presuming you've set the `version` and `arch` variables appropriately:

```
remote_file "/tmp/vcider_#{version}_#{arch}.deb" do
  source "https://my.vcider.com/m/downloads/vcider_#{version}_#{arch}.deb"
  mode 0644
  checksum "" # PUT THE SHA256 CHECKSUM HERE
end

dpkg_package "vcider" do
  source "/tmp/vcider_#{version}_#{arch}.deb"
  action :install
end
```

Comment: Thanks:)  Also....is this correct after I install? service "vcider-nmd" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

Comment: @Tampa looks plausible. I actually have the misfortune to be at a Puppet shop right now, though, so my Chef is getting increasingly rusty.

Comment: @Tampa oops -- I was starting to add something else there, and got distracted / failed to finish it before publishing the comment.