# Capturing all changes made to a system after installation

Tags: php, ubuntu, makefile, chef-infra, vagrant

This may be more of a systems question, but as I need it for a Vagrant development environment, I thought I would ask it here.

I am using Vagrant and Chef to create a PHP development environment. It's working correctly, but the setup takes forever because I'm installing PHP from source because I need some custom configurations.

Is there a way to install PHP through Vagrant once, capture all changes made by the build in an archive, so I can just unpack the archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth considering [building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source) the custom-configured PHP into a deb (or any other) package, so you actually [install already compiled PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898614/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-install-a-debian-package-using-chef) with your custom stuff inside.

It still depends how customizable you still want your build to be - I have no idea what you're actually trying to achieve as you haven't mentioned specifics of your custom PHP build.

Comment: I just used checkinstall to simplify the issue. My solution (in the form of a Chef cookbook) is posted [here](https://github.com/seagoj/cookbook-build-debian).

Comment: @seagoj Also try to look at [docker](http://docker.io) It actually allows you to run `docker diff` after you ran some commands, which will tell you exactly what has changed in the whole system after installation.