# Install RPM from file with Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I want to do the following with Chef Solo (the server is not connected to the Internet):

```
sudo yum install docker-*.rpm
```

I have the following structure:

```
cookbooks
└── my-cookbook
    └── recipes
        ├── default.rb
        └── docker.rb
```

I have this in my recipe:

```
Dir['docker-*.rpm'].each do |pkg|
  rpm_package File.basename(pkg) do
    source pkg
  end
end
```

Now, where do I put the RPM-files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the idiomatic way to install a Debian package using Chef?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898614/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-install-a-debian-package-using-chef)

Comment: Answer from duplicate candidate can be easily adapted, best bet is to use an internal http server. You may also use a private yum repo instead.

Comment: Http and custom mirror is out of the question, need to distribute the binaries and recipes in a single package, along with all dependencies.

Comment: In this acse use the files directory and the cookbook_file resource

Comment: It is never a good idea to have the rpm with the cookbook in the chef server. But just in case you can drop the rpm into <cookbook_dir>/files/default and either use remote_directly to get the rpm local on the machine to use your chef server url as rpm -i <chef-server-endpoint>/files/default/my.rpm

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that I am using Chef Solo to deploy to a single, isolated server.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be run an internal Yum repository on a host that you can reach from your production nodes.

The easy but slow/fragile way would be to put the RPMs in `files/rpms/` and use a `remote_directory` resource like:

```
r = execute "rpm -i #{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/myrpms/*.rpm" do
  action :nothing
end

remote_directory "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/myrpms" do
  source 'rpms'
  notifies :run, r, :immediately
end
```

or something like that.